# How to calculate 'compare' funtion in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mean-square-error

I am studying Root-Mean-Square Error (RMSE) and Normalized Root-Mean-Square Error (NRMSE).

According to [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) and according to [Matlab's function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/compare.html).

Why is the NRMSE value different between NRMSE manually by Wikipedia and NRMSE by `compare` code of MATLAB?

Could you teach me how to calculate `compare` function mathematically?

For example, I made like below. The method by Wikipedia:

```
Vt = 1:11;
V1 = [11.5 7.6 6.7 8.3 7.7 7.4 6.5 5.6 6.6 11.2 11.9]; % obseved data
V2 = [11.9 10.8 8.3 9.6 11.4 10.2 12.4 9.6 8.3 8 9]; % estimationd data
RMSE = sqrt(mean((V1-V2).^2)); % RMSE = 3.14107
NRMSE = RMSE/(max(V2)-min(V2)) % NRMSE = 0.71
```

The compare inner function of MATLAB:

```
% to use compare
VV1 = iddata(V1', Vt');
VV2 = iddata(V2', Vt');
compare(VV1,VV2) % -48.46%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`compare`](https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/compare.html) documentation, the estimation of NRMSE by Matlab is not the same as yours.

You need to know that there are many ways to calculate RMSE and NRMSE. From the Wikipedia article you linked on [Root-mean-square deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation):

> there is **no consistent means of normalization** in the literature.

You chose one way, and Matlab has another.

[image: fit]

So if you want to match Matlab's results, you should do:

```
NRMSE = 100*(1 - norm(V1-V2)/norm(V1-mean(V1)))
[y,fit,x0] =compare(VV1,VV2); fit
```

This returns

```
 NRMSE =
  -48.4595

 fit =
  -48.4595
```

Comment: You are amazing Thank you a lot